# Clonezilla fails at cloning with mismatched GPT and MBR partition

Tags: boot, mbr, clone, gpt, clonezilla

I got this message:

> This disk contains mismatched GPT and MBR partition: /dev/sda

Clonezilla's FAQ says:

> You might have installed an OS with GPT partition table, and later
>   overwrite the disk by installing another OS with MBR partition table.
>   The MBR partition table editor, e.g. fdisk, sfdisk, or cdisk does not
>   know GPT, so it overwrite part of the GPT partition table, but did not
>   clean the rest completely. Therefore that's why you got such a
>   message.
>
> If you are sure your running OS is using MBR partition table, not GPT
>   one, you can run sudo sgdisk -z /dev/sdx (Replace /dev/sdx with your
>   disk name, e.g. /dev/sda for the 1st hard drive) to clean the GPT
>   partition table, while keep the MBR partition table. //NOTE// Use the
>   above command carefully. It might destroy everything on the harddrive.

I installed Mac first and Windows second, then replaced the default MBR boot manager with Chameleon Boot Loader.

Here's the partition table:

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS macintosh               69.3 GB    disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS mavericks               180.0 GB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Melomano                749.9 GB   disk0s4
```

**Disk0s3** is the current MacOSX partition, **disk0s2** is a Time Machine backup and **disk0s4** is Windows 8.1.

What should I do?

Comment: What portion the FAQ don't you understand?

Comment: Everything in it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Important - Kindly Note**

Kindly request you to go through @Tetsujin's comment below.  When he tried the same answer, there was data loss.  So, I assume this answer is no longer fully correct.  Hence please research more before you take actions.

Which ever way you decide to proceed, please do take complete disk backup including the data and partitions structure (mbr, gpt) and not just the partition backup.  This way, in case things go wrong, you can revert to the original data state and try an alternative.  Without backup, you risk loss of complete data.

**Old Answer (2016) Solution**
Resolve the conflict observed by clonezilla, by removing one of the entries (gpt).  To do this, access the command line terminal of clonezilla.  Use the following command to delete the gpt.

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sda
(Press 1 to select MBR)
Press 'x' and enter to reach the eXpert mode
Now press 'z' to delete the gpt
At this step be careful, you will get an option to blank out your MBR, do **NOT** do it.
Press Ctrl + C when ever you need to exit from gdisk.
```

**Possible Cause**
When Windows gets installed in SSD, it creates a GPT.  In my system the GPT was blank.  Now when, clonezilla finds that MBR has the pariotion structure whereas GPT is blank, it throws an error.  So, when the GPT is deleted, there is no more conflict.

**Note**
Before performing this, please take a backup of your data, so that even if you accidentally delete the correct partition format, you can still retrieve your data.

Comment: I was unable to boot after this operation but hopefully I did first a backup of the first 512K (not only 512 bytes) of the disk with "dd if=/dev/sdX of=backStartOfDisk bs=512K count=1". After applying your solution, I restored partially the backup with "dd if=backStartOfDisk of=/dev/sdX bs=512 seek=1 skip=1 count=256". This last command skipped the first 512 bytes to leave them as corrected, then restored the following 256K that was missing for a normal boot. Thanks!

Comment: **This answer is dangerously wrong.** OS X at this time used a protected MBR [basically a wrapper] to hide the Mac's GUID-formatting from Windows. Clonezilla appears to misinterpret this. By removing the GPT & keeping the MBR, you are effectively destroying the OS X partition, precisely as warned against in the FAQ. Your 'possible cause' gets this exactly backwards.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for correcting me.  I will surely update the answer to link with your comment so that my answer does not cause data loss.  From your comments, my understanding is, now the way Mac OS is behaving is different - I also have not checked the latest one because I dont have a Mac now.  I am sure it did work the way I mentioned back then (2016) because I was able to boot and also did not face any data loss then.  Now, they might have reverse the design with regard to this.  Thank you for the correction :)

Comment: Newer Windows uses UEFI & GPT rather than BIOS boot on MBR, so the disk requirements are different, yes. Mac no longer uses this protective 'wrapper' & Windows can run right on GPT/GUID, so the issue shouldn't arise. Clonezilla shouldn't ever find an MBR. If it does, it's an older Boot Camp type & Clonezilla will get it wrong. Mac OS has *never* used MBR - it can see it & use it on other disk types, but it doesn't boot from it.

Comment: Though that brings up a newer issue - does Clonezilla properly understand APFS. The documentation is vague, but I would still avoid it on Mac. [I've never used Clonezilla myself because I don't trust it. I use Carbon Copy Cloner, but it's not freeware.]

Answer (score 5):

Chances are you should be using a [hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) with your setup. I don't know if Clonezilla deals well with that. If you need the hybrid MBR and Clonezilla doesn't like it, you could back up your hybrid MBR (in fact, your whole partition table) with `gdisk`, create a fresh *protective* MBR to replace the hybrid MBR, use Clonezilla, and then restore the hybrid MBR. This is a pretty advanced dance, though, so I recommend you do it only once you understand what you're doing. Read the [`gdisk` documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) and anything else (maybe the [Wikipedia article on GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)) until you understand it. (I haven't provided step-by-step details because I don't want to encourage anybody who doesn't understand it to try it.)

It's also possible that your hybrid MBR is damaged or that you've got mis-matched GPT and MBR data. In this case, you'll need to repair your partition table. The details of what you'll need to do depend on what specific damage you've suffered, and your post doesn't provide sufficient details to reveal that. The `gdisk` documentation site includes [a page on repairing GPT damage,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) which should help you get started. Posting detailed output of both the GPT and MBR data might help us understand what's going on. To do this, enter `gdisk`, type `x` to enter the experts' menu, type `p`, type `o`, and then type `q` to quit. Post the entire session output. If `gdisk` asks you whether to use GPT or MBR data when you first start it, then that means that they're badly mis-matched, and you need to decide which to use. Note that in this sort of situation, OS X is likely to use the GPT data and Windows will use the MBR data, so you'll need to carefully check *both* tables, figure out which is correct (or which *portions* of each is correct), and develop a plan to reconcile them.

If you're lucky, the fix for your problem will be easy. Be careful, though, because it's possible that you're heading into *very* treacherous waters. If you have important data on that disk, ***back it up before you do anything else!!!!***

Comment: Thank you, as you suggested the partition table was a mess, so I went with the long route and used Carbon Copy Cloner in OS X and DriveClone in Windows to backup each partition accordingly. Also Chameleon boot loader was used to replace the standard Bootcamp manager.

Comment: The problem is, cloning the disk WAS my backup solution. Now you are asking me to make a backup, before I make my backup...

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else that might struggle or face the same issue, here is a tool you can use to that will surpass the MBR - GPT issue.

WinPE this worked fine for me. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro

The downside of this software is that it is vendor specific, meaning Windows only, second it will take up 5-7GB of disk space. but if you wold like, i can can give you a copy (github repo) of my tools that I have created, that way, you won't be required to install it.

Follow the documentation on the provided link

Comment: The reason I had to relay on different resources, is because I my listed drives had information I intended to clone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm backing up HDD to samba server, I didn't give the samba user "write permission", so CloneZilla fails to 'mkdir', that is the key to my problem.

Reconfigure samba with this additional line fix my issue (don't forget to chmod -R 0770 to the shared folder)

[images]
path = /custom/hdd_images
valid users = @smbgrp
browsable = yes 
writable = yes
read only = no

# the magic ...

force directory mode = 0770