# Where is the HDD driver needed to detect Win7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, drivers, windows-pe

This question is related to the following question.

[Clonezilla stopped. Can "sgdisk -z /dev/sdx" destroy all the data on sda?](https://superuser.com/questions/904615/clonezilla-stopped-can-sgdisk-z-dev-sdx-destroy-all-the-data-on-sda)

Win7 don't boot.
I used the Win7 installation disk.
And I choosed "Repair your computer"

Win7 didn't appear on the list of OS.
But to load the HDD driver,
I could explore the content of C drive.
It's strange.
\WinPE_amd64 and \WinPE_x86 exists in the C drive.
Besides a drive X exists.
Where is the HDD driver needed to detect Win7 ?

Comment: depending on your motherboard W7 may need the mass storage sata driver for your motherboard. Post the make and model of your PC.

Comment: I tried Startup Repair in the Win7 installation disk.
Startup Repair was running more than a hour,
and after a reboot Win7 booted successfully !
In addition, the deleted Recovery resion was restored automatically, thoiugh its volume was less than 100 MB.