# macOS can't boot, shows 'prohibitory' symbol after using Clonezilla

Tags: windows-10, macos, boot-camp, partition-recovery, clonezilla

How are you?

I have a MacBook Pro Mid-2012 (A1278) running **Yosemite 10.10.5** + **Bootcamp** (Windows 10).
I mostly use the Windows partition, and rarely use macOS.

**THE PROBLEM**

I tried to clone the internal 500 GB HDD (macOS + Bootcamp) to an external 500 GB SSD, using Clonezilla Live on a USB stick.

I accidentally did something to the HDD with Clonezilla while trying to clone both partitions to the SSD. Now the HDD won’t boot in macOS and shows a ‘prohibitory’ symbol when I turn the computer on, but the Bootcamp/Windows 10 partition works fine.

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

I want to repair the HDD so that I can access the macOS partition again. I don’t want to change anything about the Bootcamp/Windows partition because it’s working fine.

**ALSO… I HAVE A BACKUP!**

I have a SSD drive with a clone of the HDD, created with Carbon Copy Cloner. It’s a few months old and boots perfectly in macOS. The only two differences are: it doesn’t have the Bootcamp partition, and it has less files than the faulty HDD (unimportant downloads).

**WHAT CLONEZILLA SHOWS WITH THE FAULTY HDD**

‘Source disk  /dev/sda does not have any partition. Clonezilla doest not support this type of source disk.’

The layout of /dev /sda:
Partition table: unknown
…  ‘osc-live-general finished with error!

[Clonezilla shows this after trying to clone the HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xLJO.jpg)

**HOW IT ALL HAPPENED**

1. I downloaded Clonezilla Live and used it on a USB stick.
2. After launching Clonezilla, it said: ‘This disk contains mismatched GPT and MBR partition: /dev/sda
   It will confuse Clonezilla and might make the saved image useless or fail to clone the disk.’
   And it showed this as well: ‘The directory for this inputted image name does not exist: /tmp/ocs_onthefly_src.8f6qjd/d2d-pseudo’
3. I tried to fix it with [this advice](https://superuser.com/a/1064181), because it worked for other users.
4. After performing step 3, I got this message: ‘Source disk  /dev/sda does not have any partition. Clonezilla doest not support this type of source disk.’
   As well as: ‘The layout of /dev /sda: …  ‘osc-live-general finished with error!’
5. Couldn’t boot in macOS anymore. It shows a ‘prohibitory’ symbol. But the Bootcamp/Windows partition works fine.

**ADDITIONAL DETAILS AND PHOTOS**

I used the SSD clone to boot in macOS, and checked the faulty HDD with Disk Utility.

On the HDD, Verify Disk and Repair Disk options are greyed out. It also shows two partitions that cannot be mounted: disk0s1 with 209.7 MB, and disk0s2 with 141.25 GB. The Bootcamp partition is fine.

For reference, the size of the SSD with the macOS clone partition is 141.17 GB.

[Clonezilla - Initial problems that I tried to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUplP.jpg)

[After Clonezilla - HDD with faulty partition #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzr7V.jpg)

[After Clonezilla - HDD with faulty partition #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IELPn.jpg)

[My backup: SSD clone with working macOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Axhe.jpg)

**MY QUESTIONS**

1. Can I use the Restore function on Disk Utility to ‘copy’ the working macOS of the SSD clone to the faulty macOS of the HDD?
   Will this damage the working Bootcamp/Windows partition on the HDD?
   (This is important to me because I work on Windows).
2. I haven’t used Winclone before. Can I use it to clone the Bootcamp partition from the HDD to an external drive, and then import it to the working SSD? Since the macOS of the HDD doesn’t boot, I’d have to do it from the SSD with the working macOS, but I don’t know if Winclone will let me do this.
3. If options 1 and 2 aren’t possible, can I easily repair the faulty HDD with Clonezilla or another free software?
4. If options 1-2-3 aren’t possible, can I install Bootcamp/Win 10 on my working macOS SSD, and then import a Windows 10 disk image?
   Will it work flawlessly, or is a ‘clean install’ better?

All advice will be appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can guess what happened, but idk how to fix it [sorry]. Clonezilla, when it says "contains mismatched GPT and MBR partition" seems to have misinterpreted the way Boot Camp at that time would make an MBR 'wrapper' to put Windows in. As a result & the advice in the linked question, rather then repair this wrapper, you've junked the GPT [GUID] leaving only the MBR. OS X wants to boot from GUID, so it now has no clue what the disk is any more.

Comment: Numbered points 1. I don't know. 2. Very likely, yes. 3. Yes, but way above my paygrade. 4. You'll probably have to start with Win7 & then upgrade from within windows. That Mac [& consequently the version of Boot Camp Assistant you will need to use] does not support Win 10. In short, you should have used CCC & WinClone from the start; would have saved all this trouble ;) BTW, Clonezilla's FAQ excerpt in the linked question warns of precisely this scenario.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you for your help! 
You're right, I didn't read the full Clonezilla manual before doing this. It worked for many people without issue.
I'll try the Winclone route and report back to you.
Have a great day.

Comment: I do wish you luck:) I could put some of this in an answer, but it wouldn't 'fix' things, just be, in effect, a catalogue of disasters… so I'll save us both the trouble ;))